# Need to scroll one WPF Grid

Tags: wpf, scroll, grid

I want to create two grids in the WPF Page. One `Grid` need scrollbar or scroll viewer. Another `Grid` is static.The grids are placed one by one in the page. How can I create and set the scroll in first `Grid`?

Comment: It sounds like maybe  you are trying to scroll both with one synchronized scrollbar? It's difficult to tell what you are asking. If you want one scrollbar for both grids, I would suggest using one overall scroll viewer for both and then just style them to look like two different grids.

Comment: Why didn't you accept any answer?

Answer (score 16):

```
<ScrollViewer>  
    <StackPanel>  
        ...   
    </StackPanel>  
</ScrollViewer>
```

Answer (score 5):

Sounds like this user justs wants the first grid to scroll, such as:

```
<StackPanel>
    <ScrollViewer>
        <Grid>
        </Grid>
    </ScrollViewer>
    <Grid>
    </Grid>
</StackPanel>
```