# How to make Grid control scroll?

Tags: c#, wpf

How to make this code scroll'able?
I've tried this solution but it won't work: [Need to scroll one WPF Grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/839062/need-to-scroll-one-wpf-grid)
My XAML (Grid named Photos has to scroll):

```
<Grid Height="533" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
    <TextBox x:Name="siteAdressTextBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="10,10,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="http://www.etrapez.pl/" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="215"/>
    <Button x:Name="sendWebRequestButton" Content="Wyślij zapytanie" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,38,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="107" Click="webRequest"/>
    <Button Content="Pobierz wszystko" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="122,38,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="103" Click="downThemAll"/>
    <ScrollViewer HorizontalAlignment="Left"  Height="460" Margin="10,63,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="1000" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" CanContentScroll="True">
        <Grid x:Name="Photos" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  Height="460" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="1000"  ShowGridLines="False" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" />
    </ScrollViewer>
    <TextBox Name="InfoBoxLabel" IsReadOnly="True" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="48" Margin="230,10,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="300"/>

</Grid>
```

Comment: Try to remove from Photos grid these settings: HorizontalAlignment="Left"  Height="460" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="1000" from Photos grid.

Comment: There's no way you're going to get any scrolling from that because the `Grid` inside the `ScrollViewer` has exactly the same size as the `ScrollViewer`. I have no idea what you're trying to do, but you should read about [WPF Layout](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/140613/WPF-Tutorial-Layout-Panels-Containers-Layout-Trans) before anything else.

Comment: HighCore - I have read WPF documentation before posting this question. I was trying to get dynamic grid with number of cells depending on number of photos found on website. When number of cells would be higher than I can insert in application window, I wanted to add a ScrollViewer in this grid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
    <Grid Height="533" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
    <TextBox x:Name="siteAdressTextBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="10,10,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="http://www.etrapez.pl/" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="215"/>
    <Button x:Name="sendWebRequestButton" Content="Wyślij zapytanie" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,38,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="107"/>
    <Button Content="Pobierz wszystko" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="122,38,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="103" />
    <ScrollViewer HorizontalAlignment="Left"  Height="460" Margin="10,63,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="1000" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
        <Grid x:Name="Photos"  ShowGridLines="False">
            <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="text here"/>
        </Grid>
    </ScrollViewer>
    <TextBox Name="InfoBoxLabel" IsReadOnly="True" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="48" Margin="230,10,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="300"/>
</Grid>
```

Output will be  http://prntscr.com/3w0cr9