# How to set scrollable bars on xaml grid with textblock

Tags: wpf, xaml

new to XAML, Im trying to set vertical and horizontal scroll bars but they are not appearing. the grid is the following:

```
                                    <Grid ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
                                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                            <RowDefinition/>
                                            <RowDefinition/>
                                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="110"/>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="60"/>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="90"/>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="60"/>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="80"/>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="50"/>
                                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                        <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Style="{DynamicResource Resource}" Text="{l:LocText CustomerStats_Last24Hours}"></TextBlock>
                                        <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Style="{DynamicResource Resource}" Text="{Binding CustomerSummaryStats.Last24Hours.Count}"></TextBlock>
                                        <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" Style="{DynamicResource Resource}" Text="{Binding CustomerSummaryStats.Last24Hours.TotalAmount, StringFormat='{}$ {0:0,0.00}'}"></TextBlock>
                                        <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="3" Style="{DynamicResource Resource}" Text="{Binding CustomerSummaryStats.Last24Hours.CheckCurrency}"></TextBlock>
                                        <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="4" Style="{DynamicResource Resource}" Text="{Binding CustomerSummaryStats.Last24Hours.AverageAmount, StringFormat='{}$ {0:0,0.00}'}"></TextBlock>
                                        <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="5" Style="{DynamicResource Resource}" Text="{Binding CustomerSummaryStats.Last24Hours.Percentage, StringFormat='{}{0:0}%'}"></TextBlock>

                                        <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Style="{DynamicResource Resource}" Text="{l:LocText CustomerStats_Last7Days}"></TextBlock>
                                        <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Style="{DynamicResource Resource}" Text="{Binding CustomerSummaryStats.Last7Days.Count}"></TextBlock>
                                        <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" Style="{DynamicResource Resource}" Text="{Binding CustomerSummaryStats.Last7Days.TotalAmount, StringFormat='{}$ {0:0,0.00}'}"></TextBlock>
                                        <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="3" Style="{DynamicResource Resource}" Text="{Binding CustomerSummaryStats.Last7Days.CheckCurrency}"></TextBlock>
                                        <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="4" Style="{DynamicResource Resource}" Text="{Binding CustomerSummaryStats.Last7Days.AverageAmount, StringFormat='{}$ {0:0,0.00}'}"></TextBlock>
                                        <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="5" Style="{DynamicResource Resource}" Text="{Binding CustomerSummaryStats.Last7Days.Percentage, StringFormat='{}{0:0}%'}"></TextBlock>
```

I tried to do the following:

```
ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
```

On the grid with no avail.

Is there a way to add scrollable bars?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WPF Grid not showing scroll bars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26737143/wpf-grid-not-showing-scroll-bars)

Comment: You should put Grid into `ScrollViewer`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Grid` doesn't support that scroll funcionality. For what you want you need to wrap the `Grid` inside `ScrollViewer`:

```
<ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition/>
                <RowDefinition/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="110"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="60"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="90"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="60"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="80"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="50"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Style="{DynamicResource Resource}" Text="{l:LocText CustomerStats_Last24Hours}"></TextBlock>
            <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Style="{DynamicResource Resource}" Text="{Binding CustomerSummaryStats.Last24Hours.Count}"></TextBlock>
            <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" Style="{DynamicResource Resource}" Text="{Binding CustomerSummaryStats.Last24Hours.TotalAmount, StringFormat='{}$ {0:0,0.00}'}"></TextBlock>
            <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="3" Style="{DynamicResource Resource}" Text="{Binding CustomerSummaryStats.Last24Hours.CheckCurrency}"></TextBlock>
            <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="4" Style="{DynamicResource Resource}" Text="{Binding CustomerSummaryStats.Last24Hours.AverageAmount, StringFormat='{}$ {0:0,0.00}'}"></TextBlock>
            <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="5" Style="{DynamicResource Resource}" Text="{Binding CustomerSummaryStats.Last24Hours.Percentage, StringFormat='{}{0:0}%'}"></TextBlock>

            <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Style="{DynamicResource Resource}" Text="{l:LocText CustomerStats_Last24Hours}"></TextBlock>
            <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Style="{DynamicResource Resource}" Text="{Binding CustomerSummaryStats.Last7Days.Count}"></TextBlock>
            <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" Style="{DynamicResource Resource}" Text="{Binding CustomerSummaryStats.Last7Days.TotalAmount, StringFormat='{}$ {0:0,0.00}'}"></TextBlock>
            <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="3" Style="{DynamicResource Resource}" Text="{Binding CustomerSummaryStats.Last7Days.CheckCurrency}"></TextBlock>
            <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="4" Style="{DynamicResource Resource}" Text="{Binding CustomerSummaryStats.Last7Days.AverageAmount, StringFormat='{}$ {0:0,0.00}'}"></TextBlock>
            <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="5" Style="{DynamicResource Resource}" Text="{Binding CustomerSummaryStats.Last7Days.Percentage, StringFormat='{}{0:0}%'}"></TextBlock>
        </Grid>
    </ScrollViewer>
```

Then it will produce this result:

[image]