# How to add Scrollbars to Grid

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, scrollbar

How does one add scrollbars to a grid?

```
    <Grid>
        <Menu Height="23" Name="menu1" VerticalAlignment="Top">
            <MenuItem Header="File">
                <MenuItem Command="ApplicationCommands.New" Header="New" />
                <MenuItem Command="ApplicationCommands.Save" Header="Save" />
                <MenuItem Command="ApplicationCommands.Open" Header="Open" />
                <MenuItem Command="ApplicationCommands.Close" Header="Exit" />
            </MenuItem>
            <MenuItem Header="Stuff">
                <MenuItem Header="Properties" Command="Properties"/>
                <MenuItem Header="Tileset" Command="Replace"/>
            </MenuItem>
        </Menu>
        <Grid Margin="0,24,0,0">
            <Canvas HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Name="canvas1" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" MouseMove="MoveMouse" MouseDown="PressDownMouse" MouseUp="canvas2_MouseLeftButtonUp" MouseWheel="canvas1_MouseWheel"/>
            <Canvas HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Name="canvas2" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" MouseMove="MoveMouse" MouseDown="PressDownMouse" MouseUp="canvas2_MouseLeftButtonUp" MouseWheel="canvas1_MouseWheel"/>
            <ListView HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="listView1" Width="203" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" SelectionChanged="listView1_SelectionChanged">
            </ListView>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
```

Two canvases may be too high or too wide.

This is Tile Map Editor and I draw everything on canvas. In the `ListView` I have tiles to insert.

Comment: Add a `ScrollViewer` around the content that should scroll.

Comment: Duplicate question of : http://stackoverflow.com/q/839062

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Usually you can wrap the element with `<ScrollViewer>` or set `ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility` and `ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility` inside the element's XAML.  I like setting to `Auto`, so that they show up only when needed.

Just try this to start:

```
<ScrollViewer>
  <Grid>
  // some code
  </Grid>
</ScrollViewer>
```

EDIT for further help!  Here's an example of a better layout, the listview is on the left followed by the two canvases. You may want to put these above each other or have a different layout, but this will show you how to do it:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Menu Name="menu1" >
        <MenuItem Header="File">
            <MenuItem Command="ApplicationCommands.New" Header="New" />
            <MenuItem Command="ApplicationCommands.Save" Header="Save" />
            <MenuItem Command="ApplicationCommands.Open" Header="Open" />
            <MenuItem Command="ApplicationCommands.Close" Header="Exit" />
        </MenuItem>
        <MenuItem Header="Stuff">
            <MenuItem Header="Properties" Command="Properties"/>
            <MenuItem Header="Tileset" Command="Replace"/>
        </MenuItem>
    </Menu>
    <Grid Grid.Row="1">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ListView />
        <Canvas Grid.Column="1"/>
        <Canvas Grid.Column="2"/>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Comment: When I did this - the vertical scrollbar was visible. But horizontal scrollbar wasn't working.
Vertical scrollbar was working for both elements - canvas and ListView (Listview is really high).

Comment: well did it need to scroll?  if you want, set the ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility = Visible.  If it is greyed out, the element doesn't need to scroll anyway.  Auto, it won't show at all then.  It sounds more like the ListView should be what is scrolling, which by default it will if needed.  the grid won't scroll if the listview scrolls already, since it will still "fit" in the grid.  What are the Canvas elements supposed to be for?

Comment: the canvas set to Stretch is also making the canvas fit the AVAILABLE grid area, so the grid won't scroll, sounds like you need to define some columns and rows for this grid, then position each canvas in it correctly

Comment: Yes, the horizontal scrollbar was greyed out. But the canvas is too wide, so scrollbar should work. I use this project to build own Tile map Editor -  http://dl.dropbox.com/u/2110010/LD22/MapEditor.zip

Comment: you need to lay out your elements in a way that makes sense.  use a grid with columns and rows or SOMETHING.  right now your two canvas elements and listbox are just on top of each other and only the grid margin is making them below your menu, this is not the way to do this. see this: http://wpftutorial.net/GridLayout.html

Comment: @Greggy i edited the answer to show you how to lay out your stuff

Comment: Thank you. I edited your code. I had also problems with dimensions of the canvas. But now it works.